# How to fetch data from multiple urls at once useffect and promise.all

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

I have a function that fetches from an endpoint in React.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    async function onLoadCreateUnitTests() {
      const results = await get('get_tables_autocomplete/b', user.user)
      autoComplete.setTablesAutoComplete(results)
    }

    onLoadCreateUnitTests()

  }, [])
```

This is just displaying values on an auto complete.

I want to also be able to fetch data from this endpoint

```
'/api/get_all_test_types'
```

I am trying too use a promise.all and I want to store the get all test types in an array.

Comment: Where's the code from what you tried?

Comment: Yeah, i'm not exactly sure how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Promise.all` takes an array of promises and returns a promise that resolves to an array of the resolved values when all the promises in the array resolve. You can then await that outer promise like so:

```js
const [result1, result2] = await Promise.all([
  get('get_tables_autocomplete/b', user.user),
  get('/api/get_all_test_types')
]);
```